# Numba делает вычислительные ошибки

Tags: python, numba

Я недавно узнал про библиотеку Numba для ЯП Python, чтобы ускорять программу за счёт компиляции функций. Как только я установил её, я сразу решил опробовать код, который вычисляет факториал 999.

```
from numba import njit, prange

@njit(parallel=True)
def main():
    s = 1
    for i in prange(1, 1000):
        s *= i
    print(s)
main()
```

Однако, на выходе я неожиданно получал **0**! Я попробовал с 99 - та же история. Решил с 9 и всё нормально. По идее, данный код должен более чем работать (никаких структур, которые Numba не понимает нету), однако, результат неадекватен от слова совсем. Пожалуйста, объясните, что могло пойти не так. Кроме ЯП Python, так уж вышло, я не знаю, поэтому если проблема связана со стороны C, распишите так, чтобы было понятно тому, кто никогда не сталкивался с низкоуровневыми конструкциями. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас переполняется тип [Int64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9696777/8324991) (его размер во всех языках программирования примерно одинаковый). Причём, происходит это гораздо раньше, в чём можно убедиться благодаря следующему коду:

```py
from numba import njit, prange

@njit(parallel=True)
def main(n):
    s = 1
    for i in prange(1, n + 1):
        s *= i
    return s

flag = True
for i in range(1, 1000):
    s = main(i)
    if (s < 0 and flag) or s == 0:
        print(f'{i-1}! = {main(i-1)}\n{i}! = {main(i)}')
        if not flag:
            break
        flag = False
```

Вывод:

```
20! = 2432902008176640000
21! = -4249290049419214848
65! = -9223372036854775808
66! = 0
```

То есть фактически переполнение произошло уже на `21!` и произведение превратилось в отрицательное, дальше его ещё сколько-то поколбасило, но в один момент заколбасило так удачно, что произведение превратилось в `0` и дальше уже понятно, ноль можно умножать сколько угодно, дальше ничего не поменяется.

Почему такого не происходит в "обычном" питоне? Потому что в обычном питоне тип `int` фактически бесконечный. Он из-за этого работает несколько более медленно, но зато не имеет таких ограничений.

Забавно, что если сделать `s` числом с плавающей точкой, то эффект будет другой:

```py
    s = 1.0
    ...
    if (s < 0 and flag) or s == 0 or s == float('inf'):
        print(f'{i-1}! = {main(i-1)}\n{i}! = {main(i)}')
        if not flag or s == float('inf'):
            ...
```

Вывод:

```
170! = 7.257415615307999e+306
171! = inf
```

Таким образом, переполнение типа с плавающей точкой происходит позже и более корректно - число превращается в бесконечность.

В общем, вам нужно почитать про типы данных и про переполнение, если хотите разобраться в вопросе. Но вообще факториал растёт очень быстро с каждым шагом и на практике такие большие числа обычно просто не используются.

Comment: Понятно. А как вы сами считаете, чтобы пользоваться Numba насколько важно знать основы C? Многие, кто программирует на строго типизированных языках говорят, что в Питоне слишком много "сахара", поэтому стоит начинать свой путь с более низкоуровневых языков. Уже вышло, что начал с Питона, но теперь задумываюсь об изучении какого-нибудь более "консервативного" языка.

Comment: @Meteoman05 Ну, скажем так, `Numba` - не для начинающих. Вернее, если бы у вас не было сверхбольших чисел и нужно было бы просто какой-то цикл, а ещё лучше цикл в цикле оптимизировать, то обычно `Numba` легко справляется и думать не нужно. Но чуть более сложное если что-то, то приходится соображать - то ли использовать `Numba`, то ли `Numpy` и векторные вычисления, то ли многопоточность, то ли асинхронность, и везде нужно понимать, как это внутри работает. А ещё есть кэширование, а ещё работа со строками медленная, а словари, а множества... И это не только в питоне )

Comment: Вообще, я планировал ускорить **Pandas**, но как только прочел немного документации на сайте Numba, я понял, что просто добавив пару строчек кода это сделать не получиться. Сверхбольшие числа вообщем-то ни где не применяются в моём случае, но тест делал именно на них.

Comment: `Pandas` нужно ускорять другими способами. В частности вычислять всё "векторно", без циклов.

Answer (score 1):

Хм, а вы представляете себе, что 999! которое вы пытаетесь вычислить -  это число с 2565 десятичными цифрами. И даже 99! -  имеет в своем представлении 154 цифры.
Рискну его здесь записать:

```
9426890448883247745626185743057242473809693764078951663494238777294707070023223798882976159207729119823605850588608460429412647567360000000000000000000000
```

Такое число в компьютере "просто так" представить невозможно, а уж работать и подавно. Да, в базовом Python теоретически можно представить целое число с (почти) неограниченным числом десятичных цифр, вот только другие пакеты с такими числами работать не будут.

Comment: Да я теперь пониманию, что в Питоне всё обстоит слишком сладко с типами данными - ни над чем заморачиваться не надо, всё и так прекрасно работает, только очень медленно. А как начинает заходить речь об ускорении - сразу всплывают моменты низкого уровня.